# PHP e MySQL - Colocando textboxs em div

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, textbox

Estou tentando uma espécie de engenharia reversa com o uso do PHP, Javascript e consulta MySQL. Estou criando um formulário de edição de eventos cadastrados em uma tabela do banco.

Em um dos campos, chamado Lista de Presença, eis como ele traz no formulário HTML o valor do campo listapresença dentro do div **numPart**:

```
<div class="BoxForm1" id="nomeParticipante">
                <br>
                <div id="numPart">
                    <?php foreach ($data['evento'] as $evento){ echo $evento['listapresenca']; } ?>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="part_text" id="part_text" value="" />
            </div>
```

No formulário que insere um novo dado, a lista de presença é composta de um ou mais textbox, dependendo de quantos participantes o evento terá. Normalmente o campo fica cadastrado da seguinte forma:

Nome 1
Nome 2
Nome 3
...
Nome 10

O que eu queria era uma forma de transformar o texto da lista de presença (o texto do div **numPart**) em vários textboxs, cada um indo do nome até o sinal de linha nova

Como posso fazer?

Comment: Quando você diz 'TEXTBOX' estaria se referindo ao `<input type="textbox">`? ou apenas está querendo criar uma 'caixa' que receberá a lista do participantes?

Comment: echo '<input type="text" value="'.$evento['listapresenca'].'" /><br>';

Comment: @AdrianoLuz é o input textbox sim

Comment: @DaltonMenezes OK, mas como eu posso fazer pra mais de um nome guardado nesse campo?

Comment: Preciso que explique melhor isso. Onde o outro nome ficaria? Qual variável ele está?

Comment: echo '<input name="listapresenca[]" type="text" value="'.$evento['listapresenca'].'" /><br>'; Pega o name listapresenca por POST/GET onde esse é um array;

Comment: @DaltonMenezes Por exemplo, se na minha tabela estiver guardado o campo da seguinte forma: "Nome 1<br>Nome 2<br>Nome 3<br>". Nesse caso será necessário transformar em três textbox. Uma contendo Nome 1, outra contendo Nome 2 e a terceira contendo Nome 3. Ou como o Mayron Ceccon falou, se houvesse uma forma de transformar em array,

Comment: Descobri como fazer, vou colocar a solução num novo post desse tópico.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri a solução. Bastou eu usar o explode:

```
<div id="numPart">
    <?php foreach ($data['evento'] as $evento){
        $participantes = explode("<br>",$evento['listapresenca']);
        for($numero=0;$numero<(count($participantes)-1);$numero++){
            echo "<div class='inputMGM'><input name='part".($numero+1)."' id='part".($numero+1)."' value='".$participantes[$numero]."' class='validate[required]'></input></div><br>";
        }
</div>
```